# How to Enter the Validated full name field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angular

.html file performed code

```
<input  type="name" [(model)]="x.name" class="form-control" pattern="[a-z]" >
```

Hello stack member's need an help from your side.
Actually I am new to angular and I want to validate the full name field in the form validation how can I edit it?

If any code has to be perform in the .ts field let me inform how to perform on it also..!

Comment: When do you want to perform validation on submit? focus? or blur. Can you elaborate on the rules for validation?

Comment: [Use a regexp website](https://regex101.com/) to build your pattern. If you encounter any issues, then post a question. We're not here to do your job but to help you in case of issues. Right now, all you did was posting a single line of HTML and asking us to do it for you ... And you didn't even follow [ask]

Comment: @alt255 hello i need to perfrom while focus condition

Answer (score 0):

catch the event on focus change , write a function in .ts and match the correct regex pattern in function with your custom input.